# Multi site ceph + proxmox

Tags: proxmox, ceph

We have 2 proxmox clusters in production.
They contain Ceph cluster with cephfs is on it.

The task is to sync files between sites. Site A is master and site B is for backup.
On site A cephfs files are created and deleted after x months.
Site B cephfs must contain the same data what is on site A. (sync or async)

cephfs-mirror will be in next ceph release so we must search another way.
For now we want to create multi-site Ceph for backup / disaster recovery.

Before doing this in production, we have created 2 clusters in the lab.
Followed by instruction in https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multisite/ we errors when starting a process "*systemctl start ceph-radosgw@rgw.`hostname -s`*".

```
Mar  4 14:10:17 lab1 radosgw[40619]: 2021-03-04T14:10:17.876+0200 7fc70306b700 -1 monclient(hunting): handle_auth_bad_method server allowed_methods [2] but i only support [2]
Mar  4 14:10:17 lab1 radosgw[40619]: failed to fetch mon config (--no-mon-config to skip)
```

Maybe you have some ideas how make this task up and running!?

Proxmox version 6.3.1
Veph version 15.2.8

P.S. rsync is last option for this task.

Comment: How would you plan to get cephfs data into rgw? Why is rsync the last option? Are your RGWs properly configured wrt to keyring and ceph.conf?

Answer (score -1):

You can replicate RBD images within a pool to a remote cluster using RBD mirroring, but I haven't heard of a way to do that for cephfs.

```
rbd mirror pool peer add {pool-name} {client-name}@{cluster-name}
rbd mirror pool enable {pool-name} {mode}
```

Comment: The question is about cephfs and the attempt with RGW, not about RBD. The rbd-mirror would be only an option if they decided to map one or multiple large RBD images where they store all their data, this image or these images could be mirrored to the remote site. But that's not what OP asked.